# Javascript - returning a variable is failing

Tags: javascript, variables, geolocation

I'm trying to do something that should be pretty simple - but it's doing my head in.
I can't seem to get a variable to return from a function

```
var where;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    where = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    // okay we have a placement - BUT only show it if the accuracy is lower than 500 mtrs
    //if (position.coords.accuracy <= 500 ) {
        // put their lat lng into google
        var meLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var image = "images/map_blue.png";
        var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: meLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: "Your location, as provided by your browser",
          icon: image,
          zIndex: 50
        }); 
    //} // end 500 mtrs test
            return meLatLng;        
    });
    alert("A: "+where);
}
```

I have a global variable called where, I'm trying to fill it with LatLng information received from the browser using navigator.geolocation - it plots the user on the map - but alert(where) always returns undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, nothing,

Bit longer answer, well... you see, the problem is that it would appear that your anonymous function returns its value to the `getCurrentPosition` function, which it seems doesnt return anything at all.

In order to use your returned value you should instead use a callBack or handle the data where it is...

Simply try replacing `return meLatLng` with `customCallBack(meLatLng)` and then defined `customCallBack` somewhere along the line.

Or, since you have already defined `where` in the global scope you could try and replace `return meLatLng` with `where = meLatLng` and then remove `where =` from `where = navigatior.geoloc....`

If what I suspect is right, the last method wont work, since I believe `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, meaning that you leave the standard flow of the application as soon as you call it. Which is why you supply a function to it in the first place.

Comment: yeah it seems it runs out of mainflow, so I'll have to look into this CallBack idea .. thanks :)